# Calculations within MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure that, when you input a class for an item, it gives you the total value. Because of this, I am having to add a calculation to my query within the SP. I keep getting an error message that reads: #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row. My guess is that it's because it's pulling from two places to get the product. Here is my code for the SP:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE totalValue (IN whichClass varchar(5),
                             OUT totalval int)
    BEGIN
        SELECT (price * numInStock) into totalval
        FROM hsitems
        WHERE itemClass = whichClass;
    END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Now, when I go to input anything and call the procedure, I am getting the error message. Here is how I was attempting to call:

```
CALL  totalValue('HW',@totalval); 
SELECT @totalval;
```

Do I need to define the calculation AS something before putting it into totalval? I attempted that, and it still gave me an error message.

Comment: You can not hold multiple values in a single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have multiple rows for `itemClass = 'HW'` in the `hsitems` table. [`SELECT .. INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) documentation specifically states:

> The query should return a single row. If the query returns no rows, a
>   warning with error code 1329 occurs (No data), and the variable values
>   remain unchanged. If the query returns multiple rows, error 1172
>   occurs (Result consisted of more than one row). If it is possible that
>   the statement may retrieve multiple rows, you can use LIMIT 1 to limit
>   the result set to a single row.

However, based on your variable name, I feel that you are trying to `SUM(price*numinstock)` instead to get the total value. This will also ensure implicit aggregation (`GROUP BY`) into a single row.

Also, by declaring `OUT totalval INT`, your output will be converted to int, and you will lose values after decimal. So I have changed it to `OUT totalval DECIMAL(10,2)`. When dealing with currency numbers, it is preferred to use `DECIMAL` instead of floating point types like `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE totalValue (IN whichClass varchar(5),
                             OUT totalval DECIMAL(10,2))
    BEGIN
        SELECT SUM(price * numInStock) into totalval  -- changed to SUM()
        FROM hsitems
        WHERE itemClass = whichClass;
    END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

---

If you want to format the sum value upto two decimal places (like currency), we can utilize [`Format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function. Also, note that output will be String format now.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE totalValue (IN whichClass varchar(5),
                             OUT totalval VARCHAR(32))
    BEGIN
        SELECT FORMAT(SUM(price * numInStock), 2) into totalval 
        FROM hsitems
        WHERE itemClass = whichClass;
    END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @CReilly what do you mean ? are you using my query exactly ?

Comment: Since this particular query/SP is dealing with money, where would I add the ROUND function to allow the call to return a number with 2 decimals? I added it into the SELECT line and it's still returning as a whole number.

Comment: @CReilly Round will not return two decimal places if the value after rounding is a whole number. You can either use `Format(number,2)` or I generally prefer to do it in the application code.

Comment: It did not work for me. :\ The query itself returns the right number, but still with no decimals. I'm still trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @CReilly why do you need two decimal places ? Any sort of formatting to be done is recommended in the application code, eg: PHP, C++, etc. If using them as number, 2 decimal places won't make any difference. For display purposes, you can format in application code (don't use SQL for display related requirements - prefer to keep SQL end simple as much as u can)

Comment: It's for a class, so I don't really have an option. The reason I need two decimal places is because it's money, and I need the cent amount. It's rounding to the nearest dollar, though I haven't added anything about rounding, so I'm assuming it's default. Everything else about the code works except for that.

Comment: @CReilly I have updated the answer to include case if you want to format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184154/discussion-between-c-reilly-and-madhur-bhaiya).